# Google Maps JavaScript API and MySQL/AJAX

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to get some data for my markers (coordinates and so on) from a MySQL Database and then add these markers to the map with a click listener to open an infoWindow.

Here is my Code:

```
  // Request to database
    function getLocations() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {                
            var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "getlocations.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var returnValue = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                for(var i=0; i<returnValue.length; i++) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icons['ice_green'].icon,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(returnValue[i][2], returnValue[i][3]),
                        title: '' + returnValue[i][1],
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent('test');
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.send();
    }  




  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 35.4681174, lng: 5.3043723},
      zoom: 17
    });

    getLocations();
  }
```

So far everything works. The markes are at the right position, BUT when I click on one off the markes, the "infoWindow" is only opened for the last added marker.

Any idea? Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're only ever creating one `infoWindow` put this line `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;` inside the `marker.addListener('click', function() {` would be my guess

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer. The code below is basically the same as the one in the second codepen.

```
var map;
var infoWindow;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

   initMap();

   var retVals = [{lat:33.808678, lng:-117.918921}, {lat:33.708378, lng:-117.918920}, {lat:33.700378, lng:-117.917920}];
   callbackAjax(retVals, map);
});

function initMap(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
 infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function callbackAjax(returnValue, map){

  for(var i=0; i<returnValue.length; i++) {
     createMarker(map, returnValue[i].lat, returnValue[i].lng, "<h1> test"+ i + "</h1><p>content</p>");
   }

   function createMarker(map, lat, lng, content){
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: 'title'+i,
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(content);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
     });
     return marker;
    }
}
```

edit:
I have made a simple code pen. maybe this helps.
http://codepen.io/zelle7/pen/dvxgVb

edit2: this codpen is maybe better for your needs http://codepen.io/zelle7/pen/XMvxzy

Answer (score 0):

Both of your solution didn´t work.

So, even when I initialize the info window inside the for loop or inside the click listener, the window only appears at the last markes :-/